# Trying to understand dressing actions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, poisson-geometry

I am reading [the lecture notes](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/preprint/file/RIMS1650.pdf) and trying to understand dressing actions.

Let $G$ be a Poisson-Lie group and $G^*$ its dual Poisson-Lie group. In the lecture notes above, Proposition 5.22 on page 80, it is said that there is a dressing action $Dr: G^* \times G \to G$ given by $Dr(g_*)(g) = h$, where $h \in G$ such that there is $h_*$ such that $g_* \cdot g = h \cdot h_*$. I am trying to understand this formula. Is "$\cdot$" the usual product of elements in a group? For example, let $G=SL_2$ and $g \in G$. How to compute the $h$ in $Dr(g_*)(g) = h$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I think that first you should understand that if your Poisson-Lie group has zero Poisson structure then the dressing action of $G$ on $G^*\simeq \mathfrak g^*$ is just the usual coadjoint action.

Let $G=SU(2)$ and consider the so-called standard Poisson-Lie group structure. This implies $D=SL(2,\mathbb C)$ and 
$$
G^*\simeq \left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ 0&a^{-1} \end{pmatrix} : a\in\mathbb R_{>0}, b\in\mathbb C\right\}\, .
$$
The fact that you can write both:
$$
D=SU(2)G^*=G^*SU(2)
$$
is just an instance of Iwasawa decomposition and a simple computation with $2\times 2$ matrices will give you quite explicit formulae. If you wish to control results you may find them here: [Ahluwalia](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9310068).

More generally the Iwasawa dcomposition, written as both a left and right Iwasawa decomposition, gives you the factorizations needed to write down in principle explicit formulae for the dressing action. I say *in principle* because in practice writing down explicit formulae for a given matrix in $SL(n;\mathbb C)$ may be quite difficult.

Of course usually you're not that interested in explicit formulae, rather in properties of this action e.g. a description of its orbits which coincide with the symplectic foliation that for a compact standard Poisson-Lie group is by now well understood.

Comment: thank you very much. I have one more question. If $G=SL(2, \mathbb{C})$, what is $G^*$ and the dressing action?